# Mantine menu item not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, mantine

We are using Menu component to show navigation menu on top. It works fine, however, for menu item, the click area is restricted to only where we have text. If we click on the remaining area then the menu just closes itself. I tried inspecting and found that the hyper link is only applied to the text.

Any suggestions?

here is the component:

```
return (
        <>
            <Menu trigger="hover" className={'${classes.menuItem} ${classes.navmenu}'} position='bottom' offset='8' withArrow> 
                {hasDropdown && (
                    <Menu.Dropdown key={'Dd_' + level}>
                        {dropdownItems.map(({ title, href, dropdownItems, index, isOffice }) => (
                            <React.Fragment key={index}>
                                {Boolean(dropdownItems) && (
                                    <NavSubItem
                                        key={'NV+' + level + '_' + index}
                                        title={title}

                                    />
                                )}
                                {!Boolean(dropdownItems) && !Boolean(isOffice) && (
                                    <Menu.Item
                                        key={level + '_' + index}
onClick={()=>myFunction()}
                                        className={classes.menuItem} // Apply custom CSS class to MenuItem
                                    >
                                        {title}
                                    </Menu.Item>
                                )}
                            </React.Fragment>
                        ))}
                    </Menu.Dropdown>
                )}
            </Menu>
        </>
    );
```

here is how it is being called: (navDisplay is an array of items)

```
<div className="col-md-auto ml-md-auto order-1 order-md-3" style={{alignContent:'center'}}>
                        <Nav>
                            {navDisplay.map(({ title, dropdownItems, index }) => (
                                <NavItem
                                    key={title + index}
                                    title={title}
                                    hasDropdown={Boolean(dropdownItems)}
                                    dropdownItems={dropdownItems}
                                    setCounty={setCounty}
                                    county={county}
                                    level={0}
                                />
                            ))}
                        </Nav>
                    </div>
```

here is what is in the array:
[image]

[image]

For example, if we click on the space near green dot then it closes the menu. The hyperlink only works if we click on the blue line area.

see image below, about what we get when we inspect the element, as we can see, the button element doesn't have any click event and hyperlink element (a) is way under it.

[image]

Comment: Can you show how this component is used? I'm guessing you pass a `<a>` tag down into the `title` prop?

Comment: updated the main description with details. It doesn't pass <a> tag.

Comment: I guess what im trying to get to the bottom of is where the link/URL is passed as it didnt look like Mantines default menu item uses <a> out of the box. Perhaps thats in `NavSubItem`?

Comment: so it seems that we don't have href always, sometimes, we have onclick event which calls javascript function. Even though it should look like a menu link. So the question is  how can we set MenuItem which calls javascript function on click? if we set onclick then again it only works when we click on the text.

Comment: Are you adding that `onClick` _directly_ to the props of `Menu.Item`? I really need to see where this `onClick` is setup and how it is used together with the menu.

Comment: yes, I do. the ```onClick``` is defined at the component level. Also, I tried ```<MenuItem trigger="click-hover" component="a" href={() => myJSFunction()}``` but it didn't worked.

Comment: updated main code to add the onClick method example.

Comment: Can you edit the OP with the component definition for `NavSubItem`?

Comment: to be clear, the problem is with ```Menu.Item``` and ```NavSubItem``` is just another compoment similar to ```Menu``` shown in the OP. sorry if it sounds confusing. I moved the onClick to ```Menu.Item``` for clarity.

Comment: And with the `onClick` in the new position have you tried that literally as is? I realise you are editing the snippet to illustrate to me, but with this very exact snippet -- i want to make sure you have actually tried that in that _precise_ configuration. I would expect the click handler to run and the menu to possibly close after (desirable behaviour). Even if clicking on the far right of the item.

Comment: The <a> tag ones, thats a different story. But need to verify above first. For the `a` tags you are actually on the right tracks with `<Menu.Item trigger="click-hover" component="a" href={() => myJSFunction()}` apart from `href` can not be a function. It must be a URL. E.g. `href="/your-url"`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use css for the component:

```
button div {
 display: block;
 width:100%
}

button div a {
 display: block;
 width:100%
}
```